# How to add items to a custom list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I know to add an integer to an integer list is:

```
List<int> myList = [];
myList.add(1);
```

I know to add a string to a string list is:

```
List<String> myList = [];
myList.add("Hello World");
```

But how do I add a set to my custom list?

```
Class MyList {
  String name;
  int price;

MyList({
  this.name,
  this.price,
 });
}
```

I want myList to be something like this at the end:

```
List<MyList> myList = [
  MyList(
    name: 'Chorizo Canapes',
    price: 12.99,
  ),
  MyList(
    name: 'Cucumber',
    price: 8.99,
  ),
  MyList(
    name: 'Eggs',
    price: 11.99,
  ),
];
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I want to do something like this:

```
List<MyList> myList = [];
myList.add({name: 'patato', price: 10})
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use `dynamic`..

Comment: Note that the price of eggs, 11.99, isn't an integer, so you should change price to `double`. Other than that, what's not working?

Comment: @Richard Heap, thanks for the correction. I want to create an empty list then add item into it. Something like: List<MyList> myList = []; myList.add({name: 'patato', price: 10}).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So what's problem? You can create this class and you can create this list. Exactly what you want.

Just note:

1. Rewrite "Class" => "class"
2. Change "price" from int to double (like Richard Heap said)
3. Don't forget to import your classes file into file where you creating list like this: 'import 'package:project/myList.dart';'

Working code:

```
class MyList {
  String name;
  double price;

MyList({
  this.name,
  this.price,
 });
}

List<MyList> myList = [
  MyList(
    name: 'Chorizo Canapes',
    price: 12.99,
  ),
  MyList(
    name: 'Cucumber',
    price: 8.99,
  ),
  MyList(
    name: 'Eggs',
    price: 11.99,
  ),
];
```

Upd: Also you can mark parameter in class constructor as "@required" (with adding "import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';") to make this parameter definitely required.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MyList {
  String name;
  double price;

MyList({
  @required this.name,
  this.price,
 });
}

List<MyList> myList = [
  MyList(
    name: 'Chorizo Canapes',
    price: 12.99,
  ),
  MyList(//Error: need parameter "name"
    price: 8.99,
  ),
  MyList(
    name: 'Eggs',
    price: 11.99,
  ),
];
```

Upd2: To create your own lists you can write

```
    List<MyList> myList2 = List<MyList>();
    myList2.add(
      MyList(
        name: 'Chorizo Canapes',
        price: 12.99,
      ),
    );
```

or

```
    List<MyList> myList3 = [];
    myList3.add(
      MyList(
        name: 'Cucumber',
        price: 8.99,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your suggestion. I didn't make myself clear in my post. I want to create an empty list, then use something like myList.add() to add item into the list in another widget.

Comment: Hi! Updated answer

Comment: You should also practice good naming coventions.  Your type `MyList` implies one element is many elements.  It should be more like `List<Item> myList2 = List<Item>[]`.

Comment: Hi Alex, im struggling to do the same.I created the class and imported the class and declared the custom list as you said. when i tried to add ,it showing "nn,not null etc" on suggestions.Where am going wrong?

Comment: I realised that initState() {} solved the problem. But why it is necessary?